# Erlang Bubble sort

Tags: erlang, bubble-sort

I'm learning Erlang and decided to implement bubble sort in it, it took me some effort and in result i've succeded, but i see that my way of thinking is incorrect, is there more effecient way to implement it or not?

```
bubble_sort(L) ->
if 
length(L) > 1 ->
    SL=bubble_sort_p(L),
    bubble_sort(lists:sublist(SL,1,length(SL)-1)) ++ [lists:last(SL)];
true -> L
end.

bubble_sort_p([]) -> [];    
bubble_sort_p([F | R]) ->
    case length(R) > 0 of
        true -> case F > hd(R) of
                true ->  [hd(R)] ++ bubble_sort_p([F|tl(R)]);
                false -> [F] ++ bubble_sort_p([hd(R)|tl(R)])
            end;
        false -> [F]
    end.
```

Comment: ...submitted an incomplete question

Comment: sorry, i've accidently submitted it, corrected now

Comment: Your `if length(L) > 1` destroys performance. It has to traverse the whole list. You are better off at pattern matching on the empty list and then handling it individually. Merge-sort is usually a better idea in functional languages. It is faster and can be written in a stable/smooth fashion as easily, but it is much faster than what you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to re-write your code in a much more readable fashion (without changing anything about the semantics):

```
bubble_sort(L) when length(L) =< 1 ->
    L;
bubble_sort(L) ->
    SL = bubble_sort_p(L),
    bubble_sort(lists:sublist(SL,1,length(SL)-1)) ++ [lists:last(SL)].

bubble_sort_p([])  ->
    [];
bubble_sort_p([F]) ->
    [F];
bubble_sort_p([F,G|T]) when F > G ->
    [G|bubble_sort_p([F|T])];
bubble_sort_p([F,G|T]) ->
    [F|bubble_sort_p([G|T])].
```

This should allow for much easier contemplation of the things actually going on in the program.

Comment: bubble_sort_p([F,G|T]) when G < F is correct, but yup it's ok, but what i'm interested in more alternative ways to implement it, Are there any?

Comment: This answer was not intended to be an actual "answer", but to help with the finding of alternative ways. It is much better readable and thus should cause less headaches for people who might want to examine the "efficiency" of the algorithm. Even though I have no idea how "efficient" and "bubblesort" would ever end up in the same sentence except for "bubblesort is not efficient, use a better algorithm".

Answer (score 5):

The implementation from the top of my head would be:

```
bubble_sort(L) -> bubble_sort(L, [], false).

bubble_sort([A, B | T], Acc, _) when A > B ->
  bubble_sort([A | T], [B | Acc], true);
bubble_sort([A, B | T], Acc, Tainted) ->
  bubble_sort([B | T], [A | Acc], Tainted);
bubble_sort([A | T], Acc, Tainted) ->
  bubble_sort(T, [A | Acc], Tainted);
bubble_sort([], Acc, true) ->
  bubble_sort(lists:reverse(Acc));
bubble_sort([], Acc, false) ->
  lists:reverse(Acc).
```

If we are talking efficiency, we obvioulsy should not go for bubble sort in the first place.

Comment: hard to read for me but quite interesting thx for answer, efficiency is irrelevant in this topic

Comment: Ok.. ;) One of the keys to really grasp functional programming is to be able to follow recursive patterns. This is actually not by-the-book bubble sort, since [A,B|T] will go on with [A|T] and put B to the result. Which means that A would keep on traveling in the list in same pass as long as it is bigger. Oh, and I think you stated "is there more effecient way to implement it or not?" in the Q.. :)

Comment: by efficiency i mean less lines of code and not algorithm efficiency actually :)

Answer (score 2):

And employing `lists:foldr`:

```
bubble(List) ->
    Step = fun
              (E,{S,[]}) -> {S,[E]};
              (E,{_,[X|XS]}) when E > X -> {swapped,[X|[E|XS]]};
              (E,{S,XS}) -> {S,[E|XS]}
           end,
    case lists:foldr(Step, {intact,[]}, List) of
        {intact,XS} -> XS;
        {swapped,XS} -> bubble(XS)
    end.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer at http://en.literateprograms.org/Bubble_sort_%28Erlang%29

```
-module(bubblesort).
-export([sort/1]).
-import(lists, [reverse/1]).

sort(L) -> sort(L, [], true).
sort([], L, true) -> reverse(L);
sort([], L, false) -> sort(reverse(L), [], true);
sort([ X, Y | T ], L, _) when X > Y ->
sort([ X | T ], [ Y | L ], false);
sort([ X | T ], L, Halt) -> sort(T, [ X | L ], Halt).
```

An example for sorting 2,4,3,5,1

sort([2,4,3,5,1])

## round 1

=> sort([2,4,3,5,1], [], true)

=> sort([4,3,5,1], [2], true)

=> sort([4,5,1], [3,2], false)

=> sort([5,1], [4,3,2], false)

=> sort([5], [1,4,3,2], false)

=> sort([], [5,1,4,3,2], false)

=> sort([2,3,4,1,5], [], true)

## round 2

=> sort([3,4,1,5], [2], true)

=> sort([4,1,5], [3,2], true)

=> sort([4,5], [1,3,2], false)

=> sort([5], [4,1,3,2], false)

=> sort([], [5,4,1,3,2], false)

=> sort([2,3,1,4,5], [], true)

## round 3

=> sort([3,1,4,5], [2], true)

=> sort([3,4,5], [1,2], false)

=> sort([4,5], [3,1,2], false)

=> sort([5], [4,3,1,2], false)

=> sort([], [5,4,3,1,2], false)

=> sort([2,1,3,4,5], true)

## round 4

=> sort([2,3,4,5], [1], false)

=> sort([3,4,5], [2,1], false)

=> sort([4,5], [3,2,1], false)

=> sort([5], [4,3,2,1], false)

=> sort([], [5,4,3,2,1], false)

=> sort([1,2,3,4,5], [], true)

## round 5

=> sort([2,3,4,5], [1], true)

=> sort([3,4,5],[2,1], true)

=> sort([4,5],[3,2,1], true)

=> sort([5],[4,3,2,1], true)

=> sort([], [5,4,3,2,1], true)

=> [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

```
-module(bubbleSort).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

sort(L) ->
    sort(L, length(L), []).

sort(_L, 0, _Res) -> [];
sort([H | _T], 1, Res) -> [H | Res];
sort(L, Len, Res) ->
    T1 = lists:sublist(L, 1, Len),
    T2 = inner_sort(T1, []),
    Last = lists:last(T2),
   sort(T2, Len - 1, [Last | Res]).

inner_sort([A, B], Res) when (A < B)->
    Res ++ [A, B];
inner_sort([A, B], Res) ->
    Res ++ [B, A];
inner_sort([A, B | T], Res) when (A < B) ->
    inner_sort([B | T], Res ++ [A]);
inner_sort([A, B | T], Res) ->
    inner_sort([A | T], Res ++ [B]).

test()->
    L = [5, 3, -1, 10, 6, 100, 99],
    ?assert(sort([])  =:= []),
    ?assert(sort([1]) =:= [1]),
    ?assert(sort([1, 2, 3, 4]) =:= [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    ?assert(sort([10, 5, 3, 2, 1]) =:= [1, 2, 3, 5, 10]),
    ?assert(sort(L) =:= [-1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 99, 100]).
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to read & understand implementation w ascending sort direction. 
Tail recursion employed, computational complexity & memory usage are classic.

```
bsort([]) ->    [];
bsort([H|T]) ->         bsort([H|T],[]).

bsort([],[]) ->                 [];
bsort([],[H|T]) ->      [H|T];
bsort([A|B], Sorted) when is_list(Sorted) ->    M = lists:max([A|B]),   bsort([A|B] -- [M], [M] ++ Sorted).
```